# ejabberd Websockets Presence

Tags: javascript, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I'm trying to implement a XMPP Client with Strophe.js. I installed ejabberd and
use it over Websockets and I installed Adium for test uses.
I tried to get the presence information from other clients, but when I track the connection via Wireshark, I can't see any Websocket package when changing the presence in Adium.
How can I get the changed presence ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked again Adium with Wireshark and figured out that neither Adium nor Psi is able to send any message via Websockets. Both are sending data directly on TCP ([PSH, ACK])